# Inno Setup using AllowGrayed

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to set AllowGrayed to False and according to the Inno Setup site this seems like how it should be done but I keep getting an "Unknown Identifier ''ALLOWGRAYED'" error when compiling. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking.

```
CompCheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(CompPage);
CompCheckListBox.Top := StaticText.Top + StaticText.Height + ScaleY(8);
CompCheckListBox.Width := CompPage.SurfaceWidth;
CompCheckListBox.Height := ScaleY(180);
CompCheckListBox.Flat := True;
CompCheckListBox.AllowGrayed := False;
CompCheckListBox.Parent := CompPage.Surface;
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option1', '', 0, False, True, False, True, nil);
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option2', '', 0, False, True, True, True, nil);
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option3', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's clearly a bug in InnoSetup documentation. To disable a particular check box in `TNewCheckListBox` you can either specify the enabled state in `AddCheckBox` method or use explicitly `ItemEnabled` property. Why do you initialize the `AllowGrayed` to False anyway ?

Comment: I don't want to disable the check box. I wanted to at disable the grayed state on the Option2 check box because it is a parent to Option3. When Option2 is checked and Option3 isn't, Option2 shows as a grayed out check mark which confuses the user because it looks like the box isn't enabled even though it is.

Comment: If you have multiple sub-items of a parent item, then you've got to have grayed state on the parent item. If you have only one sub-item of a parent item, then there's no point making it a sub-item.

Comment: What would you suggest I do if I want to give the user an optional program that they can install that depends on another? A sub-item seemed like the way to go.

Comment: @user - Not sure.. When it's a sub-item I get the impression that it's a part of the parent. Yours is rather a dependency case.

Comment: Also asked on the [Inno discussion groups](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=27785&group=jrsoftware.innosetup.code#27785)

Answer (score 1):

The [`TNewCheckListBox`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses) doesn't have `AllowGrayed` property, so what you found is a documentation bug. However, I'd say, you misused the `ACheckWhenParentChecked` parameter of the `AddCheckBox` method. That parameter set to True only for child items, not for the parents. So, try to modify your script this way:

```
...
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option 1', '', 0, False, False, False, True, nil);
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option 2', '', 0, False, True, True, False, nil);
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option 3', '', 1, False, True, False, True, nil);
CompCheckListBox.AddCheckBox('Option 4', '', 1, False, True, False, True, nil);
...
```

Here is the method prototype from the reference:

```
function AddCheckBox(const ACaption, ASubItem: String; ALevel: Byte; AChecked,
  AEnabled, AHasInternalChildren, ACheckWhenParentChecked: Boolean; 
  AObject: TObject): Integer;
```

Comment: That still does not provide an 'non-grayable' checkbox. Maybe it's not possible..

Comment: But why do you want non-grayable check box ? When you'll have a parent with two children and check only one child, the parent should be grayed. That's how I'd expect it from the user's point of view.

Comment: I don't and I agree.. But the OP does seem to want it.

Comment: Thanks I totally overlooked that. I guess I'll have to try something else for the check boxes.

Comment: @Sertac, you got me :-) Well, this can IMHO be workarounded only from the `OnClickCheck` event by a manual state change.

Comment: @user1704321, what you want is possible, but wouldn't it be misleading for users ?

Comment: Not necessarily. The way it is now it looks like the parent is only partially installed when the child is unchecked but the child program has no effect on the parent it just can't be installed unless the parent is.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (syntax for the standard components; you can adapt to a code-based page easily enough if you like):

```
[Components]
Name: parent; Description: ...
Name: parent\main; Description: ...; Flags: fixed
Name: parent\optional; Description ...
```

Associate file and other entries only with the two subcomponents -- none with the parent.  In theory, you should now have a setup where it's impossible to select the optional component without the main component, and the two appear to be independent but are in reality part of some larger system (which is only partially installed when the optional component is not installed, but that doesn't affect the main component itself).